# UITextFieldDelegate in containing View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, uicontainerview

I have implemented a container view in my `UIViewController` then placed a `UITableViewController` within it. This table contains static rows that contain a couple `UITextField`s. Now I have would like to detect when the user presses the return key on the keyboard when one of those text field's is the first responder - in the containing view controller not the table view controller. Is this possible, or is it only possible to know that in the controller the object exists in?

I attempted to do this but `textFieldShouldReturn` is not called. I conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` in the view controller's .h file, I implemented `textFieldShouldReturn`, and in order to set the `delegate` for the text fields I get a reference to the container view in `prepareForSegue` then set the `delegate` for those text fields to `self`. (I made them public so they can be accessed in the containing controller.)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Container View"]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ContainerTableViewController class]]) {
            self.ctvc = segue.destinationViewController;
            self.ctvc.firstTextField.delegate = self;
            self.ctvc.secondTextField.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't `textFieldShouldReturn` called when I hit return on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't textFieldShouldReturn called when I hit return on the keyboard?

Because you are not the delegate of the text field. That, in turn, is because you are setting the delegate too soon. You are saying:

```
self.ctvc.firstTextField.delegate = self;
self.ctvc.secondTextField.delegate = self;
```

But you are saying it in `prepareForSegue`. At that time, `ctvc` has not loaded its view yet, and `firstTextField` and `secondTextField` are still both nil. So your code here has no effect.